# jquery scrollbar

Tags: jquery, scrollbar, jscrollpane, jcarousel

I've been looking for a solution to my problem for a few days now
and was wondering if anyone from the stackoverflow community can help me.

My problem is that I need a jquery carousel and a jquery scrollbar to work hand-in-hand.
The carousel updates the scrollbar and vice versa but also information of what being displayed is within the scroll bar itself (for example (1/12) so it would be 1 of 12 of slides/image is displayed ). It would also be added bonus if I can get the scrollbar to snap and update the displayed information whenever it is in the process of being dragged or pulled.

I don't know where to start because I don't know if jCarousel supports the usage of jScrollpane with the same element.  If someone can kindly breakdown the process of what actually needs to happen it would be great.

I'm also going to try and add a diagram in case you fully didn't understand what needs to be done.

<<--------| 5/12 |------->>

That was my effort at drawing what I'm trying to explain.  As you can see the information of what carousel slide is being displayed is in the scrollbar block which is dragable.  If anyone can even point me in the right direction I would be truly grateful.

UPDATE : I have started a jsfiddle so people can take a look at what im trying to explain. I'm  using a combination of two plug-ins range input & scrollable made by the same people/team the docs be found can [Here](http://flowplayer.org/tools/rangeinput/index.html)
and the link to my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/salute_dan/LpHGq/)

ANOTHER UPDATE : Edging ever closer to how i want it to run just need help smoothing out the the script

Comment: sorry genesis i not even started writing a code for it but i have been looking into Jquery UI. P.S thank you for taking an intrest

Comment: http://www.ninaricci.com/fr/index.html#/collection/a2011/look/Look_2 as you scroll along the products using the arrows the scroll bar updates showing the displayed slide/product

Comment: FYI:  The Nina Ricci example is 100% Flash®

Answer (score 0):

### Using .animate() and .scrollLeft() :

sorry I didn't know what you wanted at first... it sounds like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mazlix/yjGzH/4/) is what you want. The real key is jQuery's [`.scrollLeft()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/) .. The example I give also uses [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to make it look nicer.

jQuery

```
$("#next").click(function(){
    $("#cara").scrollLeft($("#cara").scrollLeft() + 100);
});
$("#prev").click(function(){
   $("#cara").scrollLeft($("#cara").scrollLeft() - 100);
});
```

Comment: http://www.gucci.com/uk/category/m/men_s_shoes#look522603lookA113 if you look at this link the carousel and scrollbar work hand in hand

Comment: thanks mazlix for taking the timeout to help me its something along them lines i started a jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/salute_dan/LpHGq/51/ so maybe you can take a look and help im using a combo of 2 plug-ins made by the same people/team the docs can be found http://flowplayer.org/tools/rangeinput/index.html & here http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/index.html